# Android camera2 api + opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, android-camera2

I want to apply Android [Effect](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/effect/Effect.html) to Camera2 SurfaceTexture preview. I am very new to OpenGL, so I don't know where to start from.

I have

```
SurfaceTexture texture =  mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
```

instances, that used by Camera2 to show preview. How can I draw in on GLSurfaceView and apply effects?

Comment: You can find several examples of Camera manipulation in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika). None of them use Effect though.

Comment: @fadden they use only deprecated camera api